# how to build search functionality with ElasticSearch and lambda function into your existing project

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, serverless

I am having a Node + Express application running on EC2 server and trying to add a new search feature to it. I am thinking about using Lambda function and ElasticSearch. When the client fires a request to update a table in dynamodb, Lambda function will react to this event and update the elastcsearch index.

I know lambda runs serverless whereas my original application runs within a server. Can anybody give me some hints about how to do it or let me know if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The link between a DynamoDB update and a Lambda is "DynamoDB Streams".
The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) says, in part,

> Amazon DynamoDB is integrated with AWS Lambda so that you can create
> triggers—pieces of code that automatically respond to events in
> DynamoDB Streams. With triggers, you can build applications that react
> to data modifications in DynamoDB tables.
>
> If you enable DynamoDB Streams on a table, you can associate the
> stream Amazon Resource Name (ARN) with an AWS Lambda function that you
> write. Immediately after an item in the table is modified, a new
> record appears in the table's stream. AWS Lambda polls the stream and
> invokes your Lambda function synchronously when it detects new stream
> records.